# Translated value inside mat-option causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when lang is changed

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-translate

Select a value inside the mat-select, then click on the switch button.

You should see an 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' from the console

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ifbsaj

It happens since I have migrated my project from Angular 11 to Angular 12

Comment: This is an error of the library, report the issue there

Answer (score 0):

Injecting the `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component, and calling the `detectChanges` function after changing the language within `switchLang`, will force the Angular to detect the values that have changed after it was checked.

```js
constructor(
  private _translateService: TranslateService,
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

switchLang() {
  this._translateService.use(
    this._translateService.currentLang == 'fr' ? 'en' : 'fr'
  );
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found 2 workarounds. The easiest way is to turn the `mat-select` tag into a native `select` one.

If, on the other hand, you wish to keep using the `mat-select` element, then you can do something like this:

```js
// inside some component
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.get(["my.dropdown.keys"]).subscribe(v => {
        this.values = [
            { label: v["value1"], value: "value1" },
            { label: v["value2"], value: "value2" },
            { label: v["value3"], value: "value3" },
        ];
    });
}
```

Then, in your `.html` file, you can just use an `*ngFor` directive to populate your options.